# How can i restrict access to the files of my website?

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, custom-pages

How can i prevent users from getting the list of files that exist in my website?

For example when users type on the address bar the WebsiteAddress+/DirectoryToSearch/ they get the list of files in that directory, without getting any permission denied error

Is there any setting in asp.net that am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should disable directory browsing in IIS.

For IIS7: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109%28WS.10%29.aspx

For IIS6: Open the web site's properties in IIS Manager, and under the tab "Home Directory", uncheck the checkbox labeled "Directory Browsing".

Comment: I just did, and it rocks! But why the default setting was ON? Just curious

Comment: @strakastroukas - usually the default is disabled, you may have mis-clicked when creating the site in IIS Manager, I know I've done that before!

Comment: NOPE! This one is pasted as is In the IIS tools.
 Note:
- Default setting is ON
- Entire site will inherit this setting 
Should i contact the hosting company or what?